# github action run multiple commands in one step and re-use variable

Tags: github-actions

I have the following github action

```
  - name: Terraform Apply
    working-directory: ./config/terraform
    run: |
      echo ::set-output name=DOCKER_IMAGE::${{format('user/repoimage{0}:{steps.tagging.output}}}', ':') }} --line 1
      terraform apply -var="containerImage=${{DOCKER_IMAGE}}" -auto-approve -- line 2
```

also the part `{{steps.tagging.output}}` also causes a problem in the format.

What I want to do is to use the value in `line 1` on `line 2` without setting an output variable.  How do I do that ?

Comment: would using an `env` do the trick? if not, could you please share some more info on how you'd like to use them?